# Matlab using forward euler method

Tags: matlab-figure

dt/dx=x(1.15-0.02x-0.02y)
dt/dy=y(1.34-0.02y-0.04x)

```
T=15;
dt=1;
N=floor(T/dt);
t(1)=1;
x(1)=21;
y(1)=20;

for i=1:N   
x(i+1)=x(i)+dt*x(i)*(1.15-0.02*x(i)-0.02*y(i));
y(i+1)=y(i)+dt*y(i)*(1.34-0.02*y(i)-0.04*x(i));
t(i+1)=i*dt;
end
title('state variable')
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x,'r*-')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,y,'bo-')
```

Using forward euler method
It is correct?

Comment: Does your code return the expected result?

Comment: No... i want x&y both increasing, but y is decreasing

Answer (score 1):

I think so but you have a mistake in Your equation it shoul be

```
dx/dt=...
dy/dt=...
```